# Force VectorPlot3D to show One arrow

Tags: plotting, vector

I am plotting a curl, and I only want VectorPlot3D to show one arrow, I have tried adjusting VectorPoints-> 1, but the plot show's no arrows at all. Is 2 the minimum VectorPoints I can have?

If I cannot make use of VectorPlot3d in this way, how can I use the Arrow function to point in the direction of a vector field at a certain point?

Thank-you

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "show one arrow". Where should this "one arrow" be in your plot?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! If you post a working code snippet, you'll surely get faster & better answers. Also be sure to format the code by indenting it by four spaces or using ``.

Comment: Please also consider to register your account. This will make it possible to place comments below questions and answers and will keep account of your questions and answers and your reputation gained by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I assume the vector scaling routine needs at least two vectors. You can fake it though:

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorPoints -> {0.9999999 {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

The error message that

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, VectorPoints -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

produces

[image]

suggests that  two is indeed the minimum number of `VectorPoints`.

EDIT: Using

```
 vp1=VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, VectorPoints -> {2, 2, 2}]
```

[image]

a workaround is possible by manipulating the components of the `Graphics3D` object `vp1`:

```
GraphicsGrid[
Partition[
(vp2 = vp1; vp2[[1, 2, 1, 2]] = vp2[[1, 2, 1, 2, #]];vp2) & /@ Range[8],
4]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can specify two vectors, one of which is the vector you want, then use `VectorColorFunction` to hide the undesired one.

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 VectorPoints -> {{.5, 0, .3}, {.4, .1, .4}},
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 VectorColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, n},
   If[{x, y, z} == {.4, .1, .4}, Black, Directive[Opacity[0]]]
   ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks  for the nice example with colorfunction, I haven't come across something like this in the wolfram reference page

Comment: @Mel you are welcome :)