# VectorPoints doesn't accept value of 1?

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to plot a 3D vector field with `VectorPlot3D` but I want it only evaluated across the $xy$-plane.  I.e. I want the vectors in 3-space pointing out of the $xy$-plane, but I only want one "layer" of them vertically (where $z = 0$).  But when I specify `VectorPoints -> {8, 8, 1}` as an option to VectorPlot3D it throws an error `Value of option PlotPoints -> {8,8,1} is not an integer >= 2`.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I hacked this together by [ploting it with a large $z$ range and `PlotPoints -> {8,8,3}`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aPGI.png), then photoshopping out the top and bottom layers of vectors.  But this is really klunky and annoying as I have several of these to do.

This minimum bound of 2 for the evaluation point resolution seems pretty arbitrary and weird, not to mention really annoying for my purposes.  Is there any way I can achieve what I am attempting to?

Comment: Duplicate?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8984/force-vectorplot3d-to-show-one-arrow?rq=1

Comment: @SimonRochester Almost, it seems the OP there only wants one arrow total, I want multiple vectors but only one in the $z$-direction.  I'll try to apply some of those here though.  It baffles me that this may be impossible since this seems it should be a pretty simple task.

Comment: Specifying an explicit list of `VectorPoints` seems to work. You could also try using `PlotRange` to trim out the unwanted vectors in the z direction.

Comment: Please post code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @C.E. Just put `VectorPoints -> {8, 8, 1}` as an option to `VectorPlot3D`, and it will complain the value isn't >= 2.

Comment: @SimonRochester What do you mean "Specifying an explicit list of `VectorPoints` seems to work"?  That's what I did but it throws an error when one of the values is 1.  How do I use `PlotRange` to trim the unwanted vectors?  Could you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VectorPoints` has an alternate syntax that lets you specify an explicit list of coordinates where you want the vectors placed. `VectorPlot3D` doesn't complain if they're all in the same plane, as long as there are at least two points in total:

```
VectorPlot3D[{0, 0, Sin[Pi x]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  VectorPoints -> Flatten[Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, -1, 1, .25}, {y, -1, 1, .25}], 1], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also plot more vectors than you want in the z direction and then trim them out using `PlotRange`:

```
VectorPlot3D[{0, 0, Sin[Pi x]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -2, 2},
  VectorPoints -> {8, 8, 3}, VectorScale -> .1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could delete the unwanted arrows entirely from the graphics object:

```
DeleteCases[
  VectorPlot3D[{0, 0, Sin[Pi x]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
    VectorPoints -> {8, 8, 3}, VectorScale -> .1, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
  ], 
  Arrow[{{_, _, z1_}, {_, _, z2_}}] /; Mean[{z1, z2}] != 0, 
  Infinity
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could set the vector field to zero for `z != 0`:

```
VectorPlot3D[
  If[Abs[z] < .01, {0, 0, Sin[Pi x]}, {0, 0, 0}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  VectorPoints -> {8, 8, 3}, VectorScale -> .1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]